# objects/TxConfiguration__c.object (TxConfiguration__c.W_Page__c) -- Error: duplicate value found: <unknown> duplicates value on record with id:

Tags: apex, custom-object, ant

I am using ANT Build too to migrate the Custom Object Named as

> All Component Failures:
>   1.  objects/TxConfiguration__c.object (TxConfiguration__c.W_Page__c) -- Error: duplicate value found:  duplicates value on record with id:  (line 3, column 13)

Here is the field which I am trying to migrate...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fields>
        <fullName>W_Page__c</fullName>
        <deleteConstraint>SetNull</deleteConstraint>
        <externalId>false</externalId>
        <label>Wizard Page</label>
        <lookupFilter>
            <active>false</active>
            <filterItems>
                <field>TxConfiguration__c.RecordTypeId</field>
                <operation>equals</operation>
                <value>W Page</value>
            </filterItems>
            <isOptional>false</isOptional>
        </lookupFilter>
        <referenceTo>TxConfiguration__c</referenceTo>
        <relationshipLabel>Wizard Page</relationshipLabel>
        <relationshipName>W_Page</relationshipName>
        <required>false</required>
        <trackHistory>true</trackHistory>
        <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
        <type>Lookup</type>
    </fields>
</CustomObject>
```

Comment: 2 options available -- try to deploying first with trackHistory false OR without lookup filter. Both will work. After creation, future deployments will be working as expected

Comment: You need to include, at minimum, the fullName attribute, in order for a deploy against a custom object to work. I'm pretty sure that's why the deployment is failing.

Comment: @kurunve - If I comment that part and will deploy then what changes do I need to make in target org ?